# Backbone.js - add button tag inside li tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

Is it possible to add another tag inside one provided in `tagName`?

I have this code:

```
BookView = Backbone.View.extend(
  tagName: "li"
  events:
    "click .delete": "deleteBook"

  deleteBook: (ev) ->

    #delete operation /books/id
    @book.destroy success: ->
      router.navigate "",
      trigger: true
```

And I want to put button next inside every `li` tagname, so when someone clicks it, it would delete that record. How could I do that?

For example:

```
<ul>
<li>Some text <button type="submit">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd just add a `<button type="button" class="delete">` (not `type="submit"`, that will just cause trouble and make you do more work) to your template:

```
render: ->
  @$el.append('Some text <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>')
  @
```

Then bind to `'destroy'` events from the model in the view's `initialize`:

```
initialize: ->
  @listenTo(@model, 'destroy', @remove_and_redirect)
```

Then your `deleteBook` simply destroys the model:

```
deleteBook: -> @model.destroy()
```

and your `remove_and_redirect` would clean up and navigate:

```
remove_and_redirect: ->
  @remove()
  router.navigate('', trigger: true)
```

Simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/X3SQa/

Answer (score 0):

Use a template that contains your button.